# Word 2010 How to create different page numbers on the same page...?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

Does anyone out there know how to create different page numbers on the same page...?
While the header continues to count {page #} of {numpages}, the new page need to also restart counting {page #=1} of {sectionpages}.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Just add page number in Header as normal (you can use Quick Parts and add the formula Page write of and add again Numpages) then in another place of the page add it again Page write of and choose Sectionpages this time but you have to restart from 1 the Page (in section) in every starting section.
 Update
To restart each section from 1 first page in section, if it is in footer click on Link to previous to remove the link, click on the number to select it and on page number in the Ribbon, Format Page Number, Restart 1 
[image]

Comment: Thank you SuperSam.
Unfortunately, my problem is more complex.
The page number should also differ -- the top one shows the page number in the overall document (e.g., 10 of 16; the bottom one shows the page number in the current section (e.g., 2 of 5)

Comment: Like I wrote in the answer in each section first page right click on page number, Format Number, restart 1

Comment: When I do this, the running numbers of both numerators are reset at the beginning of the section.
I need only one numerator to reset. The other one should continue as usual...